# Get script's folder ID in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the current script's id or folder id? I'd like to be able to copy a script into a folder and have it run on folders/files specific to that folder without having to find the folder id manually.

I've tried things like 'this.getParents()' but haven't gotten anywhere.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script I wrote a while ago based on an [answer from CoreyG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770700/how-do-i-locate-the-path-of-the-folder-in-which-the-current-script-file-is-locat/14778677#14778677) that does precisely what you are looking for and just a bit more...

```
function getScriptFolderTree() {
  var thisScript = getThisScriptInDrive();
  var names = [];
  var Ids = [];
  var folder = thisScript.getParents()[0];
  while (folder.getName() != "Root"){
      names.unshift(folder.getName());
      Ids.unshift(folder.getId());
      var parents = folder.getParents();
      var folder = parents[0];
  }
  Logger.log('Root/'+names.join().replace(/,/g,'/'));
  Ids.unshift(DocsList.getRootFolder().getId());
  Logger.log(Ids)  
}


function getThisScriptInDrive() {
  return DocsList.find("poiuytrezazertyujhgfdsdcvcxyydryfhchfh")[0];
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Helpful, but not exactly what I was hoping for. You'd have to go through every copy and change up the 'junk' string.  Plus there seems to be a delay before it starts working.  I suppose it's workable, but sort of hack-y and with a several minute delay.

Comment: If you have to manually hardcode the script string every time you copy the script, might as well hardcode the folder id.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's pointless :-)  it returns the folder tree even if the file is moved in another place... but I admit it is not ideal in this specific use case.On the other hand, and as you posted it, there is no other way to get that Id.

Answer (score 0):

Theres currently no way.
Why dont you just make it so on first run asks the user to select the folder to run it at (filepicker) and save it on a script property?